# Storm targeting non-default java version

Tags: java, apache-storm

My storm cluster nodes have two java versions installed, and I can't change the default version.
Is it possible to tell Storm to run with the non-default version?

Comment: Java version you use to run Storm can be newer than Storm's compile version -- not the other way round. What do you mean by "tell Storm to run"? Did you see any problem when you tried to start Storm?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that storm-supervisor and storm-nimbus were started through upstart so they ignored environment variables. Setting their java path as an environment variable in their upstart scripts solved this.